# The correct way to create a new instance using pythoncom and force early binding

Tags: python, comtypes, pythoncom

Spent a little too much time trying to figure it out by myself...
I'm working with a FEA app called Simcenter Femap. In my program I need to create N new instances of it after I get some data from base instance for some asyncio fun. Can't even start on the asyncio part because I can't force early binding on new instances.
What is working for me at this point:

1. Created a makepy wrapper, called it PyFemap as Femap help is suggesting, made an import
2. Connected to a running instance

   ```
    femap_object = pythoncom.connect('femap.model')    
    feAppBaseInstance  = PyFemap.model(femap_object)
   ```

Every method of every Femap object works perfectly fine after this.

3. I am able to create instances using `DispatchEx('femap.model')` and invoke methods that don't require data conversion.

But for the rest of the methods to work I need to force early binding on these instances through already existing wrapper (as I see it).

"Python programming on win32" suggests that I use `gencache.EnsureModule` to create a wrapper and link it to created instance. But when I try to do it through type library's CLSID I get an error that it's not registered. Is there really no way to do it with a wrapper I already created?

Also tried to do all of this using comtypes. Some parts work better for me with it some are worse. But the end result is the same. If I may, I'd like to ask how to do it with comtypes too.
Sorry if I'm missing something really obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll post the solution since I solved the issue.
It is actually really obvious. I ended up using `pythoncom.New(...)` for multiple instances, but I think other methods would work just as well if you only need one. The issue was that I didn't attach the wrapper head class (model) to these new instances, which was pretty silly of me.

To create a new instance

```
femap_object = pythoncom.new('femap.model')
```

To assign a win32 wrapper (PyFemap) to it.

```
new_instance  = PyFemap.model(femap_object)
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using pythoncom.New(...) instead of .connect(...).

Comment: Could you explain why this solve the OP's issue?